# Java jdk.jshell.CompletenessAnalyzer

Tags: java, jshell

How do you use `jdk.jshell.CompletenessAnalyzer` ? this class is not public !
I want to implement my own shell with jshell with my own custom commands like /bin/bash .
how can implement auto completion ?
jshell support double tab for auto completion , but i can not understand how can implement for my own commands .
this is my example code :

```
import jdk.jshell.JShell;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    private static JShell jshell;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jshell = JShell.create();

        System.out.println("Custom Shell");
        System.out.println("Type '/exit' to exit the shell");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;

        do {
            System.out.print("> ");
            userInput = scanner.nextLine();

            if (!userInput.equals("/exit")) {
                executeCommand(userInput);
            }
        } while (!userInput.equals("/exit"));

        jshell.close();
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static void executeCommand(String command) {
        jshell.eval(command).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Note** : i won't to use jline .

Answer (score 1):

I have just been reading up on the JShell API, and while searching, I came across this question.

It looks like your `executeCommand()` method prints and then discards the result of calling `jshell.eval()`.

For a more sophisticated shell, you could call `jshell.sourceCodeAnalysis()`, to get a `SourceCodeAnalysis` object, which you can then use to analyze your input string to see if it is complete, or even to check for suggestions on how to complete it.

I haven't tried it yet, but what I expect to do is as follwos:

- Use the `SourceCodeAnalysis` object to parse the string into a list of snippets
- Check the state of the snippets
- Evaluate the source of valid snippets using the original `JShell` object
- Print the error messages from `ErroneousSnippet`s
- Do something clever with incomplete snippets to allow further typing to complete them